# Ruby One liner | test remote host port

Tags: ruby, sockets

I'm trying below Perl command in Ruby

**Perl**

```
perl -MIO::Socket::INET -e 'until(new IO::Socket::INET("localhost:80")) { print "Waiting for network..\n"; sleep 1}'
```

How do I same thing in ruby ?

I have tried :

```
require 'socket'
until !( TCPSocket.new("localhost",80).close ) do
        puts "Wait..."
        sleep 1
end
```

I'm looking for one liner in Ruby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difference is that Ruby will raise an error if it cannot establish the IO, so you need to rescue the error condition. It changes the flow somewhat, but is still very do-able:

```
loop { break if (TCPSocket.open("localhost",80) rescue nil); puts "Wait...."; sleep 1 }
```

---

As seen from other answer, it is possible to make a more literal conversion from the Perl version. Just use the Ruby expression `(TCPSocket.open("localhost",80) rescue nil)` to replace Perl's `new IO::Socket::INET("localhost:80")` so that Ruby's *raise an error* behaviour better matches Perl's *return undef when cannot create the object*.

Comment: Thanks... It's working perfectly.. could please suggest me any links for learning Ruby. like you.. :D

Comment: @Rahul Patil: I learnt from [The Pickaxe Book](http://pragprog.com/book/ruby4/programming-ruby-1-9-2-0), which is a good reference if you already know how to code in another language I think. Each person learns differently, so it is hard to make a general recommendation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. I will practice from that book :D

Answer (score 3):

This is similar:

```
require 'socket'
(puts "Waiting..."; sleep 1) until (TCPSocket.open("localhost",3000) rescue nil)
```

Full command line:

```
ruby -r socket -e '(puts "Waiting..."; sleep 1) until (TCPSocket.open("localhost",3000) rescue nil)'
```